# Codeigniter - check to see if the value is unique

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to check if value is unique. I have the function, but how can I check it again.

This is the function (it is working):

```
public function is_unique($field, $val)
    {
        $this->db->select($field)->where($field, $val);
        $result = $this->get();
        $result = $result['data'];

        return $bool = count($result) == 0 ? $val : FALSE;
    }
```

This is where I check the value to see if it is unique:

```
$unique_code = random_string('alnum', 6);
$unique_code = $this->posts->is_unuque('unique_code', $unique_code) != FALSE ? $unique_code: random_string('alnum', 6);
```

How can I create new value if function is returned FALSE and check the new value (make the loop until the value is unique)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
function is_unique($field, $val = null)
{
      if ( is_null($val))
      {
                // No $val supplied, so we generare a new one.
                $val = random_string('alnum', 6);
      }

      $this->db->select($field)->where($field, $val);
      $result = $this->db->get('table');

      if ( $result->num_rows() > 0 )
      {
                // Found a match
                // Try again....
                $this->is_unique($field);
      }
      else
      {
                // No match
                return $val;
      }
}
```

If you don't supply a $val, the function will generate a new random string, then check it is unique. If it's not, it tries again.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (count($result) == 0 ? $val : $this->is_unique($filed,random_string('alnum', 6));
```

may be something like this instead of returning false run function until the result is unique

```
$unique_code = $this->posts->is_unuque('unique_code', $unique_code);
```